# Vector parametric form for 2 equations and 3 variables

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, education

I need help to find the vector parametric form of the following linear system.

I have tried doing it on my own but I can't seem to get the system in the right form to get a solution.
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
x - 2y - z = -4\\\\
-2x + 4y + 3z =  1
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Could you please tell us what you have tried so far so that we can better help you?

Comment: I am sorry I am kind of new to this site so I don't know the functionalities well enough. So, I wrote the system in a matrix form such as 1.  { 1  -2  -1 = -4 } and 2. { -2  4  3 = 1}. After that I got to this point 1. { 1 -2  0 = -11} and  2. { 0  0  1 = -7}. So I know that Z is equal to -7 but I can not find out what is x and y equal to.

Comment: Baiscally, I do not know how to the solve the system in terms of 1. {1   0   z  = #} and 2.  {0   1    z  = #}. I need help to get the equations in that form and I will be able to solve it

Comment: I have a proposed a solution based on your attempt. If you still have any questions, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we add twice the first row to the second row, we get that $z = -7$, as you have mentioned.

Based on it, we obtain the relation $x - 2y + 7 = -4$. That is to say, $x = 2y - 11$.

Consequently, the solution set to this system of linear equations is given by
\begin{align*}
S = \{(2a - 11,a,-7)\in\mathbb{R}^{3} \mid a\in\mathbb{R}\}
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Well I am not sure how to write that in the vector parametric form

Comment: What about $(-11,0,-7) + a(2,1,0)$?

Comment: Ohh okay I get it Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You are welcome! Choose my answer if you think it deserves it.